# How to house and conceal an AI-level intelligence in a human body?

Tags: biology, evolution, artificial-intelligence, trans-humanism

How would you take a human body - consider it baseline for these purposes - and make it able to house, power and regulate the temperature of hardware capable of sustaining an artificial intelligence *in addition to and without replacing or in any altering the existing human intelligence*? And how would you do that in such a way as to render the subject indistinguishable from baseline when scrutinised, scanned, etc?

This is a science-based question, in that a degree of plausibility is a prerequisite, but I'm obviously looking for imaginative insights more than rigour.

### Aim

A state-directed programme to use undetectable, shackled-AI (a full AI that has been infected with thrall code) able to interface with human consciousness via chelated neural nanolacing in order to enhance a generation of babies.

### Context

Assume a mid-power 26th century culture wielding very advanced biotech and genetic engineering, quantum computing. Unlimited resources, human and financial. Widespread availability and use of nanomaterials, poor manufacturing base in terms of advanced nanotech. Rival superpower has granted AIs full legal rights, and AIs take many forms and wield much influence across that culture. Authorities actively seek out and punish individuals and firms guilty of AI-shackling, so it is essential to conceal.

Comment: Would a series of microchip implants in an essentially "wiped" brain suffice? Or do you want something a little more machine and a little less clean? Also, what are the parameters of the technology we're working with? Do we have the tech to artificially manufacture organ? If so, we could always create an artificial brain and preprogram the artificial brain with the AI. Are we working with essentially animatronics? More detail on the specifics of what you are wanting would go a longer way than just "anything goes." As is, way too broad and opinion-based.

Comment: This question is close, but is currently [POB](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437).  Tell us *exactly* how big (the volume) of the AI + power source is.  It's OK if we can squishy the volume around in the body, but we must know that volume or this is just guess work.  We also need to know how much power it's consuming so we know how much heat to handle.  Give us those *specific* numbers, and I think we have an answerable question.  Cheers!

Comment: Basically, in short, from how you're phrasing your question, the answer could straight up be "Make an artificially created human and give it a brain preprogrammed with your desired AI." It'd be 100% organic and couldn't be detectable by medicine because they'd be 100% human still. That's likely not what you want, so please give a narrow framework to build from.

Comment: Are you talking about preserving the human mind or replacing it?

Comment: Noted on POB, I've tried to refine the question more. Hopefully this helps. @SoraTamashii technological interventions that lean on biotech and genetic engineering preferred, organ manufacture is possible.

Comment: We need numbers.  Right now your question can be legitimately answered, "The AI+power is no larger than the size of a human brain and doesn't generate enough heat that it can't be cooled by blood flow."  what are our limitations?  Nobody here knows what technology will exist in the 26th century.

Comment: Why keep the brain... An AI would have its own consciousness. You couldn't conceal it from any technology advanced enough to make it. A simple scan would reveal any modification. Just by looking from the outside you wouldn't know.

Comment: @ChairmanYang That's a lot of technobabble. You can use jargon from your project in your question, but make sure your question will make sense to people who haven't read your notes. Half of the stuff in your question is now actual nonsense in the same vein as things said in Star Trek. Please, ask your question like somebody looking for help. We can't help if you seem like you a) want us to do everything for you like before or b) are trying to make it seem like you put a lot of work into it by using such vague terms to be borderline useless to explain things. My previous example answer is still

Comment: Read Old Man's War. The authir describes such technology.

Comment: just as viable as any other you could receive & I still don't for a second believe that's the answer you wanted. Please rework your question in a manner that allows us to be able to give a specific & detailed answer. As some said, almost any tech that would allow us to create this would allow someone to find it. We need a clearer path of not just what we are working with but what the world around us is working with too. I actually wrote a story similar to this premise that I'd LOVE to just feed you my main heroine's situation and let you use that for your writing, but as is, the answer fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A human body can be used to conceal and power a quite sophisticated computer, but if it is macro-scale, then this concealment may only be effective against a cursory examination or a surface scan, but against an examination by MRI or ultrasound, it would be immediately obvious.

However, a nanoscale rod-logic computer could be made the size of a single human cell, yet have the same capabilities as the human brain.  If your nanotech was not quite that good, a micro-scale rod-logic computer with the same power as a modern PC might still fit into the same volume as a single human cell, and if these were to be distributed throughout the human subject's brain, wedged between their own cells, collectively they would have supercomputer-level processing power, especially if each was also a quantum computer.

If made largely from graphene, these micro-scale computer nodes would be undetectable from a macro-scale imaging technique such as ultrasound or MRI, however nothing is completely undetectable.  X-ray crystallography techniques could reveal the presence of materials not usually found in the human body, but these would not say what function those materials had, just that they had found graphene or diamond where none should exist.  However, as this technique involves fairly high intensity x-rays, it would not be used routinely, and even if soft-x-ray-reflectance scanners were in use - contrary to modern regulations concerning exposure of humans to x-rays - they would not detect the presence of the micro-processing-nodes in the subject's brain.

The distributed computing nodes would draw a significant amount of energy, and produce a significant amount of waste heat, and while the human body is quite capable of tolerating and shedding this excess heat, a suspicious person with a background in sports physiology and time to observe the subject - on the order of weeks to months - might notice that the subject's energy input was significantly higher than their weight, activity levels and baseline metabolism should account for.  However, the distributed computing nodes could easily conceal their presence should their host be subjected to metabolic rate testing, simply by powering down to a low-power mode for the duration of the tests.

An electroencephalogram might show slightly odd brain waves *if* the nodes were actively affecting the host brain, but it wouldn't detect the operation of the nodes themselves.

Likewise, positron emission tomography would only detect unusual brain activity if the host brain was being affected by the processing nodes, but would not detect the operation of the nodes themselves.

Answer (score 3):

I read your question as

> Is there a way to sustain superhuman intelligence without looking different than an ordinary human?

The straightforward solution is to put a further brain somewhere in the abdomen or ribcage. Minor improvements such as a speedier neurotissue would also do some share of superhuman intelligence, but you probably want more.

So, my answer is **more wrinkles**. Correct me, if I am wrong, but the grey matter plays quite a role in the intelligence, the number of cells and connections is somewhat related to the surface of the brain. So, let's increase the brain surface by more and finer wrinkles. The nice side effect is that the white matter does not change much. So, one could plow deeper into neurology and find out, what is increased and what remains at human levels.

IF you need a *drastic* improvement of intelligence, you'd need to outsouce thinking to a moon-sized brain *elsewhere* ("Worm"-style), connected via a broadband faster-than-light communication channel. Or just warp the metric to make the skull larger inside than outside. However, physical side effects, such as inertia, might still apply.

Comment: Nice. I like the idea of putting the AI brain somewhere else and covertly dialing in.

Answer (score 2):

A human body can already house an AI level of intelligence. All you need is the tech to clone a human and the tech to program the brain.

As for scanning, it really depends on the level of scanning you'd want to be able to pass. I suspect the brainwaves of an AI wouldn't look anything like a human. They'd be far more ordered.

Comment: What do you base that suspicion on?

Comment: An MRI picks up things like autism and some mental illnesses from which parts of the brain are active. They can even crudely read thoughts. https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/health/a27102/read-thoughts-with-brain-scan/

Comment: Have my +1 then.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you are talking 26th century biotech...
I like the idea of a ton of organelles in each cell that are biologically constructed and each act as nodes that together form the AI. If they communicate with each other to form "thoughts" using something like radio that'd be a dead give away. I like the idea of using quantum entanglement for no-eavesdropping comms between the bio-AI nodes. You could have the nodes in blood cells that are moving throughout the body do maintenance by entangling and distributing the entangled pairs to allow for continuous communication - if you go this route I think blood flow with actually limit bandwidth (how fast your AI can think). Since communicating with entangled pairs destroys the entanglement (as far as I remember anyway), they will need to be continually replaced.

The tricky bit is that I don't know if this will hold up to DNA or blood tests. These AI nodes would be like mitochondria with their own genetic code (or some other molecular code) so they can self replicate or even be passed on to kids. But we can sequence mitochondrial DNA pretty easily. My only thought on that is that they could self destruct if they think they are being tested/sequenced by some outside force. Then it's just more cell junk that's not really distinguishable from the host human.

Answer (score 0):

You put the AI in his wheelchair and tell people it's a text-to-speech device which works via detecting eye-movements. They aren't going to scan the chair, or if they do, and find computer parts inside, well, that's just how it works.